How is Google Trends Formula Calculated?
Here is the Google Trends website showing "Search Interest" over time: https://trends.google.ca/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&geo=CA&q=olympics,covid,pizza&hl=en-GB
I wanted to compare the popularity of different searches (COVID PIZZA OLYMPICS) , for example:

I am wondering for each color, at each date - how is the index between $0$ to $100$ calculated?
I found this link here https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4365533?hl=en but I am not quite sure I understand it.
This was my attempt to understand what is going on:
Suppose we take the term "Pizza". Let's say we have the following searches for "Pizza".

Week 1: 500 searches
Week 2: 1000 searches
Week 3: 750 searches
Week 4: 250 searches

Assume the total search volume for all terms in each week is as follows:

Week 1: 100,000 searches
Week 2: 120,000 searches
Week 3: 110,000 searches
Week 4: 90,000 searches

First, normalize the search volumes at each week:
$$
\text{Normalized}(t) = \frac{\text{Search Volume for "Pizza"}(t)}{\text{Total Search Volume}(t)}
$$

Week 1: $\frac{500}{100,000} = 0.005$
Week 2: $\frac{1000}{120,000} = 0.0083$
Week 3: $\frac{750}{110,000} = 0.0068$
Week 4: $\frac{250}{90,000} = 0.0028$

Next, find the maximum normalized value (i.e. max pizza):

Maximum normalized value = 0.0083 (Week 2)

Scale the normalized values to a range of 0 to 100:
$$
\text{Index}(t) = \left(\frac{\text{Normalized}(t)}{0.0083}\right) \times 100
$$

Week 1: $\left(\frac{0.005}{0.0083}\right) \times 100 \approx 60.24$
Week 2: $\left(\frac{0.0083}{0.0083}\right) \times 100 = 100$
Week 3: $\left(\frac{0.0068}{0.0083}\right) \times 100 \approx 81.93$
Week 4: $\left(\frac{0.0028}{0.0083}\right) \times 100 \approx 33.73$

So it seems that this is showing relative popularity of the term Pizza with respect to itself? Is this correct?

There is Normalization , though it is not by total volume , it is by max volume taken over "Weekly Interval" according to Data.
Smaller interval ( last 12 months ) where Pizza is higher shows this :

Here we can see that max volume for Pizza is the "New Year Week 2024" , which is then taken to be $100\%$
Everything else is a Percentage of this , hence those values will be between $0\%$ & $100\%$
In your Case , the max volume for COVID was "Christmas Week 2021" , which is then taken to be $100\%$
ADDENDUM :
When Normalization is via total volume , there might be no way to get $100\%$ when there are multiple Non-Zero Data Points. Hence it is clear that total volume is not used here.
